# How to rotate a part of label axis with several variables in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I take the same example published  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462368/how-to-label-an-axis-with-several-variables-in-r-ggplot2)

So the dataframe is as follows:

```
results <- data.frame(Name=factor(c("Mark", "Mark", "Sue", "Sue")), 
           Tutor= factor(c("Eric", "Eric", "Richard", "Richard")),
           Test= factor(c("Maths","English","Maths", "English")),
           Score= c(100,91,88,71),
           Percent=c(100,91,100,80.7),
           school.year= c(2,2,5,5))
```

I have taken the first proposed solution to label an axis with several variables so :

```
 results$label <- paste(results$Name,results$Tutor,sep='\n')

 ggplot(results, aes(y=Percent, x=label, colour=Test, fill=Test)) +
 geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
 ggtitle('Test Results') +
 ylab('Percent')
```

We obtain this graph

[image]

Now I would like to rotate (90°) only the first row of the x axis labels as shown in this graph:

[image]

Is there a way to do this? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the best way, but you can use `annote()` from `ggplot` to do this.
I changed the label from `Tutor` and `Name` just to `Tutor` and added a text-label for the `Name`.

```
results$label <- paste(results$Tutor)
row1 <- results$Name

    ggplot(results, aes(y=Percent, x=label, colour=Test, fill=Test)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge') +
  ggtitle('Test Results') +
  annotate(geom = "text", x=results$label, y=-5, label=row1, size=3, angle = 90)+
  ylab('Percent')
```

[image]

Of course you can adjust the size and position of the added text label.